# When the verb precedes the noun "percentage", a singular verb is required

Tags: grammar, there-is, agreement, percentages

According to Garner's fourth edition

> When the verb precedes the noun *percentage*, a singular verb is required. That is,
>
> *a higher percentage of them **are***, but *there **is** a higher percentage of
> them*

I'd love to have some elaboration on this point because I could't find any related information at all.

Does this singular have to do with the pronominal *there* itself in general?

***EDIT***:

> Though serving as a plural when the need arises, *series* is ordinarily
> a singular noun. But it is also a noun of
> multitude, so that phrases such as *a series of things* take a plural
> verb. However, the collocation ***there {has been - is} a series* has predominated**
> in print sources.
>
> Common nouns of
> multitude: *lot, majority, mass, minority, multitude,
> percentage, proportion, variety*.

According to *Microsoft® Encarta® 2009,*

> If you put the indefinite article a before *percentage*, use a plural
> verb when the noun or pronoun in any subsequent prepositional phrase
> is regarded as a countable plural, not a unit or a whole: *A large
> percentage of the errors are found in this text*. If the noun or
> pronoun object in such a phrase is singular or is regarded as a unit
> or a whole, use a singular verb: *A large percentage of the electorate
> remains undecided*.

However, a counterexapmle:

> If you are speaking of the senators as individuals, say ***A** majority of the senators **have cast** their votes*

Comment: Would it be wrong to say e.g. *There are a higher percentage of people attending than hitherto*? I guess it would - presumably because the verb is governed by the singular word "percentage", rather than the plural "people".

Answer (score 1):

*The American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style* (2005) says on page 353:

> When preceded by *the*, *percentage* takes a singular verb: *The
>   percentage of unskilled workers is small*. When preceded by *a*, it
>   takes either a singular or plural verb, depending on the number of the
>   noun in the prepositional phrase that follows: *A small percentage of the workers are unskilled. A large percentage of the crop has spoiled*.

When the anticipatory pronoun "there" is used, the indefinite article is normally used (We usually say: *there is **a** percentage...*, NOT *there is **the** percentage...*), and because of the phenomenon known as "number by proximity", the singular "percentage" calls for a singular verb regardless of whether a singular or a plural noun follows.

- There **is** a large percentage of spoiled crop.
- There **is** a small percentage of unskilled workers.

I'd also add that using a singular or plural verb actually seems to depend on whether the verb refers to the noun "percentage" or to the noun that follows:

- The **percentage** of spoiled crop **is** large / The **percentage** of unskilled workers **is** small. (We are speaking about the percentage being large or small.)
- A large percentage of **crop** **has** been spoiled / A small percentage of **workers** **are** unskilled. (The crop, not the percentage, has been spoiled / The workers, not the percentage, are unskilled.)

With "there is", the focus always lies on the existence of a certain percentage, and that's why the singular is used.

*The American Heritage Guide* does not seem to have taken into account this case, in which the singular is used irrespective of the number of the noun in the *of*-phrase accompanying ***a*** percentage of:

- **A** large percentage of spoiled **crop** **is** equivalent to a disastrous harvest.
- **A** small percentage of unskilled **workers** **is** acceptable.

Comment: If you put the indefinite article _a_ before percentage, use a plural verb when the noun or pronoun in any subsequent prepositional phrase is regarded as a countable plural, not a unit or a whole: _A large percentage of the errors are found in this text_. If the noun or pronoun object in such a phrase is singular or is **regarded as a unit or a whole**, use a singular verb: _A large percentage of the electorate remains undecided_.
Microsoft® Encarta® 2009

Comment: What does **a unit or a whole** means here? I've found this counterexample with the word MAJORITY: If you are speaking of the senators as individuals, say _**A** majority of the senators **have cast** their votes_  (Microsoft® Encarta® 2009)

Answer (score 1):

Especially in the UK, such problem nouns as 'percentage' (singular-form nouns referring to an actual plurality) are usually given notional agreement of the following verb:

- 'A higher percentage of them are ...' corresponds to 'More of the population are' (etc).
- 'A higher percentage of it is' indicates mass usage, corresponding to 'A higher percentage of waste is being recycled' say.

But the choice between 'There is / there are' ('non-referential-there' constructions) with say 'a percentage' (and the research here is confined to this one 'noun of multitude) is subject to a proximity-agreement override; the 'there is' choice (and note that *there's* is often used in some obviously plural contexts, such as 'There's a lot of people out today,' 'There's many a slip twixt cup and lip,') is vastly more common.

*Google search data*:

- 'there are a small percentage that still' [+ V]: [3 examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=QMuFXo_nCsKD8gKT172QAg&q=%22there+are+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&oq=%22there+are+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoECCEQClCLuxdYycAXYObXF2gAcAZ4AIABRIgBsgGSAQEzmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiPh_DE0MnoAhXCgVwKHZNrDyIQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)
- 'there are a small percentage who still'  [+V]: [0 examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=xMyFXu2wK5TzgQbhjKiADg&q=%22there+are+a+small+percentage+who+still%22&oq=%22there+are+a+small+percentage+who+still%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DL3ANYtOMDYIDqA2gAcAB4AIABO4gBkgKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjtopL-0cnoAhWUecAKHWEGCuAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)
- 'there is a small percentage that still' [+ V]: [10 800 examples; first 20 all count usages](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&ei=Hc6FXu7rHMvIgQbg0rnwBA&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiu7sSi08noAhVLZMAKHWBpDk4Q8tMDegQIDBAs&biw=1310&bih=736)
- 'there is a small percentage who still' [+ V]: [only 4 examples, one with a singular verb-form!?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1310&bih=736&ei=Vc6FXpnGJseX8gKFyb-YCQ&q=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+who+still%22&oq=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+who+still%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1D72hRYp-QUYOzoFGgAcAJ4AIABQogBsgGSAQEzmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjZxKi908noAhXHi1wKHYXkD5M4ChDh1QMICw&uact=5)
- (again, not many examples for 'there's a small percentage who/that still')

The verb-form after 'There is a small percentage that still' where we are in an obviously count situation obeys *either* 'grammatical' or notional (note that both are equally grammatical!) agreement, examples being:

- '... there is a small percentage that still believes it does not cause cancer' [[UC San Diego](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1310&bih=736&ei=V9CFXsraOqWAhbIPycChwAE&q=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&oq=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DNjgpY35gKYMOcCmgAcAB4AIABUIgBwAKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiK4siy1cnoAhUlQEEAHUlgCBgQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)]
- ' ... but there is a small percentage that still are living in the past' [[University of Rochester {blog site?}](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1310&bih=736&ei=V9CFXsraOqWAhbIPycChwAE&q=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&oq=%22there+is+a+small+percentage+that+still%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DNjgpY35gKYMOcCmgAcAB4AIABUIgBwAKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiK4siy1cnoAhUlQEEAHUlgCBgQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)]

The Google search data indicate, it would seem, that even people who usually use notional agreement (and I find it more powerful and on occasion less problematic, if requiring more thought on occasion) prefer to use 'There is' before 'a [higher / substantial ...] percentage ...' even when that percentage corresponds to a plurality of referents, and who would use a plural subsequent verb-form

('There *is* a higher percentage of people today who *believe* that viruses can be extremely dangerous').

Comment: what are the data for the same sentennces without _"small"_? how does percentage compare to **majority**? Garner's: _Among the common **nouns of multitude** are **bulk, bunch, flood, handful, host, majority, mass, minority, multitude, percentage, proportion, variety**_

Comment: You have other questions to post? Your OP asks wisely (and as ELU requires) about **one** 'noun of multitude' only. And I think some have been addressed here before. //  I'd use 'there are' before a bunch, host, majority/minority where appropriate, mass, multitude and variety, obviously only with count referents.

Comment: [Liberman, at Language Log {2007}](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004035.html), investigates the idiomaticity of 'There is/are a bunch of ...' and his figures show that _are_ is the overwhelming favourite here. As with 'number'. He says that this is the prevailing trend with all nouns of multitude, but that individual corpus studies are required to do justice to each particular noun.

Comment: What are the data for the same sentennces without "small"?  why did you include "small"? Liberman did not include "small".

Comment: Words such as 'significant', 'small', 'large' make 'there are a Ø percentage ...' far more idiomatic. Note that Garner adds a premodifier (and you were happy to use that example). Also note that you can work out the corresponding data yourself.  Reasonable research is expected on ELU. Though I've checked; all results are too few to be statistically meaningful.

Comment: Instead of a premodifier, Liberman uses a postmodifying prepositional phrase, so it'd be _"there is/are a percentage of..."_

Comment: "Though serving as a plural when the need arises, _series_ is ordinarily a singular noun. But it is also a noun of multitude, like _lot_, so that phrases such as _a series of things_ take a plural verb. However, the collocation **there {has been - is} a series** has predominated in print sources."