# A large percentage is or are

Tags: verb-agreement

I found this sentence in a book:

> A large percentage of the population **smokes** too much.

The author treated the phrase *'a large percentage of'* as singular. I am so confused with the use of verbs after *'a large percentage of'* as some folks on the Internet consider *'a large percentage of'* plural.

Do we have any rules for the phrase? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Gustavson's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529445/when-the-verb-precedes-the-noun-percentage-a-singular-verb-is-required), including <<  'using a singular or plural verb actually seems to depend on whether the verb refers to the noun "percentage" or to the noun that follows:

The percentage of spoiled crop is large / The percentage of unskilled workers is small. (We are speaking about the percentage being large or small.) ...

Comment: A large percentage of crop has been spoiled / A small percentage of workers are unskilled. (The crop, not the percentage, has been spoiled / The workers, not the percentage, are unskilled.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the verb precedes the noun "percentage", a singular verb is required](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529445/when-the-verb-precedes-the-noun-percentage-a-singular-verb-is-required)

Answer (score 2):

The construction *a large percentage of…* is not plural, but is rather an example of a **number-transparent** construction, where the number agreement is determined by the **oblique**, i.e. the noun phrase that is the complement of  *of*.

In your case there is another complication, namely that the oblique in question, *the population*, has a [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) noun (*population*) that is a **collective** noun. Such nouns are formally singular, but they allow for optional **plural overrides** (as in *the police **are** here* instead of *the police **is** here*). These overrides are more common in British English than in American English, but they do happen in American English as well.

In short, the number agreement of the whole phrase *a large percentage of the population* will depend on whether *population* is taken on its face value as singular, or whether we choose to employ a plural override for it. This is why, in this case, you see that some people use a singular verb, and some plural.

**Discussion**

Most of the time in English,

> the verb agrees with a subject with the form of an NP whose person-number classification derives from its head noun.

That type of agreement is called **simple agreement** ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), p. 499). In your sentence,

> *A large percentage of the population smokes too much.*

we *seem* to have a simple agreement. Namely, the subject of the sentence is the noun phrase (NP) *a large percentage of the population*. The [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of that NP is the noun *percentage*, which is a singular noun. Thus the verb *smokes*, which is also in the singular, would seem to agree with that singular noun.

But appearances can be deceiving, as evident from the following examples, all from the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

> For example, he notes that **a large percentage of the -ump rimes have** a three-dimensional sense to them.
> **A large percentage of the new immigrants come** as educated professionals… 
> …**a large percentage of the entering students are** not true freshmen…

In these examples, the simple agreement fails: all the verbs are plural, despite the fact that *percentage*, which is the head noun of the subject NP, is singular. It seems that the fact that *percentage* is a singular noun does not matter after all.

**Singular and plural overrides**

What is going on here is the following. In English, there can be departures from simple agreement. When the departure is systematic enough so that one can describe it in terms of certain rules, we say that the expression in question exhibits a singular or plural **override** (CGEL, p. 501). There are different types of overrides, which are sometimes obligatory and sometimes optional.

One of the nouns with which overrides can happen is *percent*. In your sentence you have *percentage*, which behaves similarly to *percent* as far as overrides.

In order to explain what happens, it will be helpful to consider several other cases of override first.

**Background: two relevant examples of override**

A very clear case of obligatory override happens with **number-transparent non-count quantificational nouns.** A typical example is illustrated in

[5]  i  *[A lot of work] **was** done.*
      ii  *[A lot of errors] **were** made.*

In [5], the number agreement is determined by the **oblique,** the noun phrase (NP) that is the complement of *of*. Here are some other nouns that can function similarly to *lot* in this respect: *plenty, lots, bags, heaps, loads, oodles, stacks, remainder, rest,  number,* and *couple* ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468),  pp. 349-350).

Another override that will be relevant is the optional plural override that can happen with collective nouns:

[8] *The committee has/have not yet come to a decision.*

The noun *committee* is singular, and so simple number agreement would dictate a singular verb. However, there can be an optional plural override. CGEL explains it as follows (p. 502):

> The optionality of the override with collectives reflects the fact that there is potentially a difference of meaning between the versions with singular and plural verbs. From one perspective a committee is a single entity, but since a committee (normally) consists of a plurality of members it can be conceptualised as denoting this plural set. The construction with a plural verb focuses on the members of the committee rather than on the committee as a unit. The plural override is therefore not permitted with predicates that are applicable to the whole but not to the individual members; it is, moreover, of questionable acceptability if the collective has *one* (or *a/another*) as determiner:
>
> [10]  i  *The committee consists/<sup>*</sup>consist of two academic staff and three students.*
>          ii  *This committee, at least, is/<sup>*</sup>are not chaired by one of the premier's cronies.*
>         iii  *One committee, appointed last year, has/<sup>?</sup>have not yet met.*

**Overrides with *percent***

NPs whose head is the noun *percent* are subject to overrides. Here is CGEL (p. 504):

> **Proportional constructions with *per cent* (BrE) and *percent* (AmE)**
>
> [16]  i  *One percent of students <sup>*</sup>takes/take drugs.*
>         ii  *One percent of the electorate takes/take drugs.*
>        iii  *One percent of the cheese was/<sup>*</sup>were contaminated.*
>
> *Percent* is best analysed here as a noun taking an *of* complement (and for that reason we have used here the single-word AmE spelling). It belongs with the number-transparent nouns, with plural *students* in [i] requiring a plural verb and singular *cheese* in [iii] a singular verb: compare *a lot of students* and *a lot of the cheese*. In [ii] the head of the *oblique* is electorate, and since this is a collective noun, singular agreement can be overridden, just as in *The electorate aren't going to like this.*

***A large percentage of…***

As we have seen above in the examples from COCA, the phrase *a large percentage of…* seems to be number-transparent: for the purposes of subject-verb number agreement, what matters is whether the oblique (the NP that is the complement of *of*) is singular or plural.

But when the oblique is a singular collective noun, it is itself subject to optional plural override.

In COCA, that option does not seem to be taken very often, at least not in the academic portion of its collection:

> **A large percentage of the island's population depends** on the French welfare system.
>
> **A large percentage of the world's population lacks** access to safe drinking water.
> **A large percentage of the population was** dislocated from their ancestral territory.
> When such **a large percentage of the population is** involved in vehicular usage, …

The optional plural override with collective nouns is more common in British English. We can get a rough estimate of how much more by comparing the number of hits for "population is" and "population was" to the number of hits for "population are" and "population were".

Of course, a good portion of the hits will be false positives, e.g. if the full phase is *many in the population are/were…*; here *population* is not the head, while the actual head, *many*, normally has a plural agreement and is not number-transparent. But the same type of false positives will happen in both the American and the British corpus.

In COCA, the (apparent) singular agreement is more than seven times more numerous than the plural agreement. But in the *British National Corpus* [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), it is only 3.3 times more numerous.

And so it is not surprising that in the BNC we find an example where *a large percentage of the population* is used with a plural override for *population*:

> **A large percentage of the population appear** to be earning their living as 'consultants' of one description or another.

Comment: Not the first correct answer, but definitely the best.

Comment: Although I'd say notional agreement prevails in the UK.  'A large percentage of the population is working from home' sounds very natural (though not mandatory) to my UK/notionalist ears, whereas 'A large percentage of the population are visual learners' is virtually forced. Gustavson (above and duplicate) expresses/explains this succinctly.